# How to change the font of some textOutput elements?

Tags: css, r, shiny

In server.R I have a bunch of metrics from this week stored in output as well as the previously measured metrics.

```
output$x1_current_week  <- renderText(values[['x1']])
output$x2_current_week  <- renderText(values[['x2']])
...
output$x1_previous_week <- renderText(values_previous_week[['x1']])
output$x2_previous_week <- renderText(values_previous_week[['x2']])
...
```

in my ui.R i want to display both the current and previous week's values in a box with the current week in the center using custom font/color defined in css and the previous week below it using the same font as just plain html.

Shown below is what I'm trying to achieve. I've hard coded the previous week value.

[image]

the ui code to achieve this  is as follows

```
box(
    ...
    html("<p align='center'>x2</p>"),
    h3(textOutput('x2_current_week'), align='center'),
    html("<p align='center'>previous week: A</br>")
   )
```

How do print the previous week's value in the html displayed font and add text around the value? I've tried using paste() but the textOutput is the only part that is displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add CSS to elements with style tags. (Or include them as a CSS file, see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).) I think this can guide you in the right direction:

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$style("#x1_current_week {font-size:20px;
               color:red;
               display:block; }"),
    tags$style("#x1_previous_week {font-size:15px;
               display:block;
               bottom: 12px; 
               position:absolute;
               width: 100%;
               left:0px;}"),
    div(style="text-align:center;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        padding-top:70px;
        position:relative;",
        textOutput("x1_current_week"),
        textOutput("x1_previous_week")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output)
{
  output$x1_current_week  <- renderText("x1 this week")
  output$x1_previous_week <- renderText("x1 prev week")

}


shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Super helpful answer, thank you Florian for sharing it